# How to shorten these jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these 3 jQuery functions that basically do the same thing, but they are a tiny bit different (width of window, and class that is removed/toggled)

I need the functionality of all these 3 functions, but want to somehow combine them/shorten them into one function. I've tried to but my code keeps breaking
Can anyone help to shorten them?

Here are the 3 functions

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    if (($(window).width() > 670) && ($(this).hasClass('exampleimgopen'))) {
      $(this).removeClass('exampleimgopen');
    } else if ($(window).width() > 670) {
      $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen');
      $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen');
    }
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    if (($(window).width() < 670) && ($(this).hasClass('exampleimgopen2'))) {
      $(this).removeClass('exampleimgopen2');
    } else if ($(window).width() < 670) {
      $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen2');
      $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen2');
    }
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    if (($(window).width() < 540) && ($(this).hasClass('exampleimgopen3'))) {
      $(this).removeClass('exampleimgopen3');
    } else if ($(window).width() < 540) {
      $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen3');
      $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen3');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need the functionality of all these 3 functions, but want to somehow combine them/shorten them into one function.

Generally, a good approach when refactoring similar functions is to create a single factory function that will take your variable data as arguments and return a function that has access to that data via its closure.

```
function myFactory(conditionFunc, windowWidth, cssClass) {
  return function() {
    $('.about').hide(600);
    var windowCondition = conditionFunc($(window).width(), windowWidth);
    if (windowCondition && ($(this).hasClass(cssClass))) {
      $(this).removeClass(cssClass);
    } else if (windowCondition) {
      $('.exampleimg').removeClass(cssClass);
      $(this).addClass(cssClass);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call this function 3 times to build your functions:

```
// helper methods that will perform '<' or '>' on window width
var lessThan = function(a, b) { return a < b; };
var greaterThan = function(a, b) { return a > b; };

var func1 = myFactory(greaterThan, 670, 'exampleimgopen');
var func2 = myFactory(lessThan, 670, 'exampleimgopen2');
var func3 = myFactory(lessThan, 540, 'exampleimgopen3');
```

Which you can then pass each into their corresponding listeners.

```
$('.exampleimg').click(func1);
$('.exampleimg').click(func2);
$('.exampleimg').click(func3);
```

The advantage of doing things this way is that you only write a single function which then creates different versions of your listener callback functions, based on the data you give to it.

Comment: Why is better to return a function rather than execute the code itself?

Comment: because the code needs to be executed in a listener, not right away

Comment: Thanks, although how do I pass the functions to their listeners? I tried this for one of the functions but it's not working - ` $( document ).ready(function(){
 $( ".exampleimg" ).click(function func1() {
     });
    }); `

Comment: Uhm, `$(window).width() < windowWidth` <- note that the first function flips that around and uses `>` instead ?

Comment: This answer does not account for the fact all three functions are click handlers for exactly the same class.  What happens if he has called `$('.exampleimg').click(func3);` and the window is  600 wide?

Comment: @Tibrogargan The question wasn't to improve the logic of his code, it was to refactor 3 functions into a single one. My answer doesn't affect the behavior of his code, just shows how to clean up the code. In the example you give, both OP's code and my code would behave the same, which is not do anything.

Comment: @RobertDeniro You need to pass the newly created function directly as the listener, not create a new one that is called the same. Check out my edits for an example

Comment: Perhaps we have a different understanding of his intention.  The question as stated is ambiguous - it's unclear what is supposed to happen if the window is under 540 wide (should both classes be affected or just 1?).  What happens if the window is exactly 670 wide?  What is meant by 'combine'?  IMO your answer does not attempt to combine his logic

Answer (score 0):

I think is maybe closer to what you wanted, although it's unclear what you wanted to have happen when the width was < 540.  Might want to use `if .. then ... else` instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var classes = [];
        if (width < 540) {
            classes.push('exampleimgopen3');
        }
        if ($(window).width() < 670) {
            classes.push('exampleimgopen2');
        }
        if ($(window).width() >= 670) {
            classes.push('exampleimgopen');
        }
        classes.forEach(function(class) {
            $('.exampleimg').removeClass(class);
            if (!$(this).hasClass(class)) {
                $(this).addClass(class);
            }
        });
    });
});
```